# UITableView Display JSON or Object, which one is better

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Usually, we request to get some JSON data, then display it in a UITableView, do we really need to convert the JSON to object then display it?

For example, the data retrieved from the server:

```
[
   { 
     key1: value1,
     key2: value1,
     key2: value3
   },
   { 
     key1: value1,
     key2: value1,
     key2: value3
   },
   ...
   { 
     key1: value1,
     key2: value1,
     key2: value3
   }
]
```

**Option 1** Display directly

we save these data into an array:

```
var jsonArray = [[String: Any?]]()
```

And in tableView cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let jsonElement = jsonArray[indexPath.row]
  cell.configure(jsonElement)
}
```

**Option 2**: Convert it to a struct/object to display.

Define the object/struct:

```
   struct JsonObject {
       var key1: String
       var key2: Date
       var key3: Int
    }
```

Convert:

```
let jsonObjects: [JsonObject] = jsonArray.map { jsonElement in
   JsonObject(convert(jsonElement))
}
```

Display

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let jsonObject = jsonObjects[indexPath.row]
      cell.configure(jsonObject)
    }
```

So which option is better? Does the convert has some performance issue we should care about?
Thanks!

Comment: You should not care about performance unless you face performance problems. Using a properly parsed object is type-safe.

Comment: Parsing the JSON into a model makes the code more readable, more type-safe and more maintainable. To make up for performance hit, which is minimal at worst in my opinion (you can find [here](https://github.com/bwhiteley/JSONShootout) a graph of the various JSON parsing libraries and their performance metrics), that can occur due to JSON serialization; I'd recommend using small objects for your datasource and implementing a load more feature which loads the datasource as the user scrolls.

Comment: Technically both methods are valid which renders this question primarily opinion-based.